# How to enter the style of a div and modify it if other divs have the same class?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an accordion but I don't know how to enter the style 'accordion__content' which is inside
'accordion' to modify the display from block to none.

I want to make an accordion but I don't know how to enter the style 'accordion__content' which is inside 'accordion' to modify the display from block to none.
I want to make an accordion but I don't know how to enter the style 'accordion__content' which is inside 'accordion' to modify the display from block to none.
I want to make an accordion but I don't know how to enter the style 'accordion__content' which is inside 'accordion' to modify the display from block to none.

[Code Pin Here](https://codepen.io/Hessler7/project/editor/ZGyWpW)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | FAQ Accordion Card</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="imgback" src="/design/desktop-design.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="container">
    
    <img src="images/illustration-box-desktop.svg" alt="" class="box__svg">
    
    <div class="sub__container">

      <img src="images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg" alt="" class="bg__svg">
      <img src="images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg" alt="" class="women__svg">
      

      <div class="faq">

        <h1 class="faq__tittle">FAQ</h1>

        <div class="accordion__container">

          <div class="accordion">

            <div class="accordion__tittle">
              <h4 class="tittle">How many team members can I invite?</h4>
              <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__content">
              <p >You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
                team members for the Premium plan.</p>
            </div>

          </div>

          <hr>
  
          <div class="accordion">

            <div class="accordion__tittle">
              <h4 class="tittle">What is the maximum file upload size?</h4>
              <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__content">
              <p>No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space. 
            </p>
            </div>

          </div>
          
          <hr>
          
          <div class="accordion">

            <div class="accordion__tittle">
              <h4 class="tittle">How do I reset my password?</h4>
              <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
            </div>            
            <div class="accordion__content">
              <p>Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile 
                A reset link will be emailed to you.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          
          <hr>

          <div class="accordion">

            <div class="accordion__tittle">
              <h4 class="tittle">Can I cancel my subscription?</h4>
              <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
            </div>            
            <div class="accordion__content">
              <p>Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</p>
            </div>
                        
          </div>

          <hr>

          <div class="accordion">

            <div class="accordion__tittle">
              <h4 class="tittle">Do you provide additional support?</h4>
              <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__content">
              <p>Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal</p>
            </div>
            
          </div>

          <hr>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  


  <script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");


for (let i = 0; i<acc.length; i++){

    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        
        
        /* var panel = this.nextElemenSibling;
        console.log(panel);
        if(panel.style.display === "block"){
            panel.style.display = "none";
        }
        else{
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }  */
    
    });
    
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `this.children[1]` in your JS to target the accordions child with the class of `accordion__content`

Then you can create a class that will add a display of none to the `accordion__tittle` elements, adding by default in the HTML. Use JS to toggle it on the click event listener.

I did not clean up your CSS just show you how to add/remove using the conditional you have already written.

Alternatively you can just write the conditional to check if the `el.style.display = block` then add/remove like you did in your code pin.

**NOTE**: *I removed all the other html and CSS to just focus on your question.*

```js
const acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion")

// much cleaner JS
for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active")
    this.children[1].classList.toggle('display-none') // toggle the class .display-none no conditional needed
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}


/*ACCORDION*/
/* Added this class to use for toggling display of none to your accordian elements */
.display-none {
  display: none;
}

.accordion__container {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 15%;
}

.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.active .accordion {
  background: green;
}

.accordion__tittle {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.accordion__content {
  height: 40px;
  width: 90%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.active {
  background-color: seagreen;
}

hr {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.attribution {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion__container">

  <div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion__tittle">
      <h4 class="tittle">How many team members can I invite?</h4>
      <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__content display-none">
      <p>You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion__tittle">
      <h4 class="tittle">What is the maximum file upload size?</h4>
      <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__content display-none">
      <p>No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion__tittle">
      <h4 class="tittle">How do I reset my password?</h4>
      <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__content display-none">
      <p>Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion__tittle">
      <h4 class="tittle">Can I cancel my subscription?</h4>
      <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__content display-none">
      <p>Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion__tittle">
      <h4 class="tittle">Do you provide additional support?</h4>
      <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__content display-none">
      <p>Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>

</div>
```

Comment: for some reason in the console I got "undefined" so I used this.lastElementChild. I have to practice the different ways, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To select all the elements with the same class:

```js
const accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');
```

This is a NodeList, kind of the same as an array which has index start from 0.
If you want to select the first accordion, then:

```js
const youAccordion = accordions[0];
```

and so on.

Comment: I haven't tried this solution yet, I have to practice other ways. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must get this.lastElementChild property in click handler function,  your function will be:

```
....
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");        
        //var panel = this.nextElementSibling;//
        var panel = this.lastElementChild;
        console.log(panel);
        if(panel.style.display === "block"){
            panel.style.display = "none";
        }
        else{
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
 });
....
```

Comment: I found it very useful, thank you very much.